# Displaying products from categories in woocommerce

Tags: plugins

I want to display thumbnails of multiple categories on a page, i am having hard time accessing the categories as it shows empty. is something wrong with my code?

```
                  $args = array(
                        'per_page' => '12',
                         'category_name' => 'travel',
                         'orderby' => 'title',

                    );


print_r($args); //nothing gets output, like categories
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    print_r($args); //nothing gets output, like categ

    //want to display the thumbnail

endwhile;;
    endif;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing bad array keys to `$args`. Do something like this:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '12',
        'product_cat' => 'lead-generation',
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'title',
    );


$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

the_post_thumbnail('full');
    //want to display the thumbnail

endwhile;
    endif;
```

There is no `per_page` key, use `posts_per_page` instead.

Woocommerce category taxonomy slug is 'product_cat'. The 'category_name' is for normals posts. You must target the post type of woocommerce, here it is `product`.

Comment: nothing get output or displayed. if i do `print_r($args)` the array code return same as displayed above.

Comment: did you change the product category to your category slug? and if you do print_r($args) the array always output the same array keys and values.

Comment: how do i know which parameters to give in args, do i look into database? like product_cat

Comment: No way. Try to google it, it will take you to the [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Answer (score 0):

For product filter with 3 products and with Featured title:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'product_cat'  => 'Featured',
    'order_by' => 'title',
);
```